# UITableViewCell with UITextField losing the ability to select UITableView row?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am almost done implementing a `UITableViewCell` with a `UITextField` in it. Rather then going through `CGRectMake` and `UITableViewCell.contentView` I have implemented it the simpler way:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
    amountField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 190, 30)];
    amountField.placeholder = @"Enter amount";
    amountField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
    amountField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    amountField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever; 
    [amountField setDelegate:self];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Amount"];
    [cell addSubview:amountField];
    return cell;
}
```

And then I also implemented the `didSelectRow` method, resigning the textField to allow showing the other fields input views.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    [amountField resignFirstResponder];
    ...
}
```

This works smoothly, only thing is there are other rows in the table, when those others are selected the entire cell is selected and turns Blue, while the one with my UITextField doesn't, I mean the field is selected and I can enter text but the cell is not selected.
I have tested it and figured out the problem is in the line:

```
[cell addSubview:amountField];
```

It seems that this breaks the selectable cell behavior, and even adding it to `[cell contentView]` doesn't fix this. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If the text field has *userInteractionEnabled* set to *YES*, and it fills the entire cell, you can not get the cell to listen to touch. In order to get the cell to respond to touches, you need to set the *userInteractionEnabled* of the text field to *NO*.

**Edit:** And if you want to make the text field editable, when the cell is selected, add the following code in *didSelectRowAtIndexPath:* method,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // get the reference to the text field
    [textField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: If you set `userInteractionEnabled = NO;` would this not render the UITextField uneditable?

Comment: Apparently not: I have followed EmptyStack advice and set   [amountField setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]; at the beginning of DidSelectRow method, and then [amountField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES] only when selected row is the one with the text field. Selection is now ok, but I have to tap twice on the row to actually enter text...

Comment: @micpringle, Ofcourse. He can not have both text field and cell respond to touches as the text field fills the cell.

Comment: @Fabrizio Prosperi, You have no need to tap twice on the cell. You can call `[amountField becomeFirstResponder]` after the line `[amountField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: Thank you EmptyStack that did the trick, and your solution it's the simplest and working smoothly here!

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out, if I'm understanding this all correctly, that there's no easy way to dynamically determine which UITextField is associated with a given UITableViewCell. Thus, @MicPringle's approach may be more effective for multiple UITableViewCells.

Comment: if I have multiple textFields in the same cell, assume I have a form? How would I make all of them become firstResponders? Is it possible?

Comment: Not working in Xcode 10.0, iOS 12.1, swift 4.Please help.

Answer (score 6):

You've not *broken* anything by adding a subview, instead the UITextField is capturing the touch ahead of the UITableViewCell. You can test this by tapping outside of the UITextField but within the bounds of the UITableViewCell and you'll see it does in fact still select as you would expect.

To get round this, you could subclass UITextField and add a UITableView property. Set the property when you instantiate the UITextField and add it to the cell.

```
amountField.tableView = tableView;
```

Then you'd need to override **becomeFirstResponder** in your subclass, and in the method get the row for the cell with the UITextField and then select it manually

```
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    // Get the rect of the UITextView in the UITableView's coordinate system
    CGRect position = [self convertRect:self.frame toView:self.tableView];
    // Ask the UITableView for all the rows in that rect, in this case it should be 1
    NSArray *indexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForRowsInRect:position];
    // Then manually select it
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[indexPaths objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This also works, but it required a lot of additional code, while setting the text field userInteractionEnabled=NO as suggested below by EmptyStack was a couple of lines of code....at least until I find some other problem :) Thank you for your help though, it made the issue clearer.

Comment: Is this not a retain cycle? `tableView` -> `visibleCells` -> `amountField` -> `tableView`

Comment: @jakenberg true, the `tableView` property on `amountField` should be specified `weak` in order to avoid a potential retain cycle

Comment: Don't forget to call [super becomeFirstResponder];

Answer (score 1):

First Thing is you havent used reusable cells. The coding which you provided will cause a lot of memory.

Next thing is you can select the row by touching the area other than the textfield.

One solution for your ques is

In your textField Delegate

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[textField superView];
cell.selected=YES; //I think this will call the didSelectRowATIndex;
```

I am not sure this will work. But worth a try.

Comment: Apart the fact that this table is 4 cells only because it's a nice input mask, so memory shouldn't be a big problem, but why are u saying I have not used reusable cells? I thought I did. I am going to try your solution now. Thanks.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the reusable concept.. See here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html... Anyway 4 cells is ok but with a row of more than 10 will get you a problem.

Comment: I might have misunderstood of course, but reusing cells when they all have different controls inside shouldn't be avoided? Anyway thanks for the link :)

Comment: I tried also your solution, implemented in textFieldShouldBeginEditing, it works, but requires then other code to deselect the cell when selecting the others. Anyway is a good hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you needed to use reuseIdentifier for cellForRowAtIndexPath, reason if you do not use reuseIdentifier is: when you scroll up and down, it will always allocate new cell and new textfields so you need to put cell==nil condition, so revised code is here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (cell==nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier] autorelease];

     UITextField *amountField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 190, 30)];
     amountField.placeholder = @"Enter amount";
     amountField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
     amountField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
     amountField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever; 
     [amountField setDelegate:self];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:amountField];
}
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
[[cell textLabel] setText:@"Amount"];

return cell;
}
```

In didSelect delegate method you can do like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [prevField resignFirstResponder];
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  UIView *view = [[cell.contentView subviews] lastObject];
  if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]{
     currentField = (UITextField*)view;
  }
  [currentField becomeFirstResponder];
  prevField = currentField;
}
```

Comment: Guys, I appreciate your effort to teach Cocoa best practices, but I tried to put there the only relevant code, amountField is not instantiated every time, but only at view did load, check with !cell is there but I omitted because not relevant to my question, and my table doesn't scroll because it's 4 rows only. The rest of your comments are very helpful though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

inside the cell for row at index path add this line which is given in bold,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];

    amountField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 190, 30)];
    amountField.placeholder = @"Enter amount";
    amountField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
    amountField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    amountField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever; 

    [amountField setDelegate:self];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Amount"];

    **for (UIView *cellSubViews in cell.subviews) {
            cellSubViews.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }**

    [cell addSubview:amountField];
    return cell;
}
```

try this, it will work