# How to focus a UICollectionViewCell in UITableViewCell in tvOS?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

### Description:

I have a list of `UITableViewCell`s that have each have a `UICollectionView` with X amount of `UICollectionViewCell`s (see image below for more clarity)

The idea behind this is to be able to implement sections with a header on top and a horizontal scrolling `UICollectionView`

Everything is working great, except when I try to focus the `UICollectionViewCell`s (aka: `CategoryCell`). The `UITableViewCell` gets focused and highlights all the content making it impossible to focus any of the `UICollectionViewCell`s.

### What I've tried:

According to other posts the fix for this would be deactivate User Interaction and/or set the selection style to none on the `UITableViewCell`:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

and to enable User Interaction on the `UICollectionViewCell` instead.

Here are posts that talk about it:

[UITableViewCell with UITextField losing the ability to select UITableView row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579904/uitableviewcell-with-uitextfield-losing-the-ability-to-select-uitableview-row)

[How can I disable the UITableView selection highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190908/how-can-i-disable-the-uitableview-selection-highlighting)

I've attempted to implemen these solutions without success.

### Question:

What step did I miss? Does the fix not work on tvOS? How do I focus my `UICollectionViewCell` that is in a `UICollectionView` that is in a `UITableViewCell`?

### More:

[image: Table View Controller]

*Image showing my UITableViewController and all it's contents from my StoryBoard.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is most likely that your table view cells are returning `true` to `canBecomeFocused`. You can disable that by either implementing the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView(_, canFocusRowAt:)` to return `false`, or by subclassing `UITableViewCell` and returning `false` from `canBecomeFocused`.

The focus engine will try to focus on the top-most view that returns `true` from `canBecomeFocused`, which is why it can't find your collection view cells: they're "hidden" inside the focusable table view cells. If you disable focus on the table view cells, then the focus engine will be able to find your collection view cells.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canFocusRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and it didn't work. My collection cells can not be focused on when I use siri remote to try and navigate between the collection cells. I can scroll up and down in the tableview but that's about it. Any help is appreciated.